# Redirection in Apache 2.4 - get rid of port numbers and redirect to server's name on HTTPS

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2.4

I have an application, it can be accessed in a browser through server's IP address followed by the port number or through server's name followed again the by port number. So currently this two options are:

- http://192.168.20.20:8080
- http://app.mydomain.net:8080

The application can also be accessed through HTTPS in similar manner (HTTPS + port for HTTPS):

- https://192.168.20.20:8181
- https://app.mydomain.net:8181

I would like to make a redirection in Apache 2.4 which will redirect all above mentioned sites to one working on HTTPS:

- https://app.mydomain.net

Below are some examples how this redirect should work.

| Original | Redirected |
| --- | --- |
| http://192.168.20.20:8080/settings/display | https://app.mydomain.net/settings/display |
| https://app.mydomain.net:8181 | https://app.mydomain.net |
| https://app.mydomain.net:8181/dashbord/axcf.php | https://app.mydomain.net/dashbord/axcf.php |
| http://app.mydomain.net:8080/home/a/b/c/d | https://app.mydomain.net/a/b/c/d |

So, I need to cut out the port number, take everything beyond it and add it to `app.mydomain.net`, and also redirect every possible way of getting to my app to `https://app.mydomain.net`.

Could you please help me resolve this problem? In the configuration file I was able to create simple HTTP to HTTPS redirection using VirutalHosts, which redirect from for example http://app.mydomain.net to https://app.mydomain.net:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName app.mydomain.net
   Redirect permanent / https://app.mydomain.net/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName app.mydomain.net

  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried with below commands, but they doesn't work for me. I have properly SSL configured and `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName app.mydomain.net

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName app.mydomain.net

  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```